# Nuxt 3 deployment to digitalocean causes error because of unsync package files

Tags: deployment, digital-ocean, nuxt3

I'm following these steps for deploying my Nuxt 3 app to Digital Ocean:

https://nitro.unjs.io/deploy/providers/digitalocean

But during the build I got this error:

```
npm ERR! `npm ci` can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
```

My local environment is `node v16.20.0` and `npm 9.6.6`.

In `package.json` I have set:

```
"engines": {
   "node": "16.x",
   "npm": "9.x"
},
```

I tried to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and re-install it on the local but it didn't help. I also tried to deploy the same app to Vercel and there was no error during the build.

Has anybody ran into this type of error?

Thank you.

### Update

So using `npm v7.x` works. But I think it's related to this issue:
https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4942